# Sufficiency Condition for PIDs

Tags: ring-theory

Letting $R$ be an integral domain, the challenge is to prove that (i) every $a,b∈R$ has a gcd which can be written as an $R$-linear combination of $a$ and $b$, and (ii) for every sequence $a_1,a_2, ...$ such that $a_{i+1} \mid a_i$ there is an integer $N$ such that $a_n$ is the product of $a_N$ and a unit for all $N ≤ n$, necessarily implies $R$ is a PID.

Taking an ideal $I$ and a countable generating set, and then taking successive gcds and using $a_N$ as a principle generator, it is evident that a counterexample must be uncountably generated. However, I'm not sure where to proceed next, or if it's even a useful result to exploit.

If $N$ was bounded for all sequences, it would be simple to finish, but that's not what the wording leads me to believe in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition (ii) tells you that $R$ satisfies the ascending condition on principal ideals, that is, any sequence
$$
(a_1) \subseteq (a_2) \subseteq \dots \subseteq (a_i) \subseteq (a_{i+1}) \subseteq \dots\tag{seq}
$$
is eventually constant, that is, it stops at some $(a_N)$, for some $N$.

So suppose $I$ is a non-principal ideal, so that in particular $I \ne \{ 0 \}, R$. Take $a_1 \in I$, $a_1 \ne 0$, $a_1$ not invertible. Then if possible take a proper divisor $a_2 \in I$ of $a_1$ which is not invertible, etc. So you are building a sequence like (seq) contained in $I$. We will obtain $(a_N)$ which is *properly* contained in $I$, and it is not properly contained in any principal ideal contained in $I$.

Now take any $b \in I \setminus (a_N)$, and use (i) to show that the ideal $(a_N, b)$ is principal, and $(a_N) \subset (a_N, b) \subseteq I$, a contradiction.